# Gamma colour difference on across windows

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

This is a very odd and almost not reproducible bug for me.
Some time my gnome-terminal would starts with the "correct" color as in the right of the image, but most of the time it looks like on the left.

The environment variables are identical across 2 windows. Including $TERM.
Any helpful pointers?

[image: screen]

Comment: Checking the colors of the picture, the left window contains colors that are part of the standard 256-color palette, the colors of the right window are different. So I can think of three main possibilities: 1) It's the left half that's okay and the right one is broken for whatever reason; 2) The right window uses true colors and for some reason vim thinks they're not available in the left window; 3) You have some special gamma correction set up which should always apply but in the left window it's skipped.

Comment: For the 3rd case I assume you'd know about the gamma correction you applied, please share details of that then?

Comment: The next time you encounter this behavior, please do the following. First, run `echo -e '\e[48;5;246m FOOBAR \e[m'` in both windows. What background color does it produce in each of the windows, compared to vim's "NORMAL" in the status line? Second, execute `echo -ne '\e]4;246;#949494\a'`, does it (and if so then how) change the background color of the previously printed "FOOBAR" word?

Comment: Yet another thing to try: start `script`, then start `vim`, quit `vim` and then quit script's shell. You're notified that a new file called `typescript` was created. Rename this file, and repeat these steps in the other window. Open the two files and compare them, is there any notable difference, e.g. is perhaps the left window's one full of `^[[38;5;...m` (where `...` is actually a number) (38;*5* stands for 256 palette colors) while the right window's one full of `^[[38;2;...;...;...m` (38;*2* is for true colors)?

Comment: @egmont Thank you, turned out your first case is correct: the right terminal did run a script to override the original 256 color palette to that of true color. So it is actually the "wrong" one.
My Vim version 7.4.1689 do not support true color as far as I know.

Comment: [Allegedly](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) vim supports true colors since 7.4.1770, so close call, but yours just doesn't support it.

Comment: For curiosity, please let us know if you figure out which script modifies your 256-color palette :-)